# full rank by inspection

Tags: matrices, matrix-rank, stochastic-matrices

I have an $n\times n$ matrix where each row is a probability vector. In the $2\times 2$ case, the matrix has full rank so long as the two rows differ. I wonder whether for $n \geq 3$ there is still any way to determine whether the matrix has full rank by "comparing rows" without calculating the eigenvalues or determinants.

Comment: Probably not. While I don't fully understand the context, I imagine this has to deal with matrices whose entries on each row sum to $1$? I've almost never really seen a $3 \times 3$ matrix or bigger whose rank was obvious on inspection, unless some rows were clearly duplicates or scalar multiples of singular rows. Once you throw in the dependence on multiple rows in linear combinations, it just becomes too much of a mess, most of the time, to see independence or the lack thereof, in my experience. (I'll be glad to be proven wrong though!)

Comment: Check that the dot products of any two rows or any two columns are nonzero

Comment: That's what Gaussian elimination does, compare rows by subtracting them, without calculating the determinant.